# Angular 2 firebase database service

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to have a service in an Angular2 app that does all the database work. All the tutorials I see use http instead of firebase so they aren't really helpful. I have the service constructor pull the data I'll need from the database, however when a page tries to get data from the service, it doesn't get anything because the database call hasn't finished yet. I'm starting to feel like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602927/angular-2-service-pointless), that there isn't any point in putting network calls in a service, that they should all be duplicate code in each controller instead of putting all the DB code in 1 service. Here are my files:

**lesson.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class Lesson {
  constructor(public id: number, public buttons: Object[]) {  }
}

@Injectable()
export class LessonService implements OnInit {

  private lessons: Lesson[] = [];
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.object('/lessons', { preserveSnapshot: true }).subscribe(lessons => {
      lessons.forEach(lesson => {
        this.lessons.push(new Lesson(
          lesson.key,
          lesson.val()['buttons']
        ));
      });
    });
  }

  getLessons() {
    console.log('getting lessons', this.lessons);
    return this.lessons;
  }

  getLesson(id: number): Lesson {
    // return new Promise()
    console.log('getLesson', this.lessons);
    return this.lessons.filter(lesson => {
      return lesson.id === id;
    })[0];
  }
}
```

**lesson.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Lesson, LessonService } from '../lesson.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'lesson',
  templateUrl: './lesson.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lesson.scss']
})
export class LessonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() lessonID: number = 0;

  lesson: Lesson;
  constructor(public service: LessonService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lesson = this.service.getLesson(this.lessonID);
    console.log('view lessons', this.lesson);
  }
}
```

**lesson.html**

```
<lesson [lessonID]="selectedId"></lesson>
```

When I try to load the lesson component, it sees that there is no lessons because `this.lessons` isn't filled out from the DB from the service's constructor. The only 'solution' I see is to remove the lesson service, and do DB calls every page load, which in my mind defeats the purpose of doing a single page app.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good idea to call getLesson inside your ngOnInit as the
service that you injected may still initializing as well.

I had the same problem with my code before but after moving my code to
ngAfterViewInit(), it fixed the problem.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
...
...

export class LessonComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() lessonID: number = 0;

  lesson: Lesson;
  constructor(public service: LessonService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.lesson = this.service.getLesson(this.lessonID);
    console.log('view lessons', this.lesson);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still have the same problem, I think I got it to work in a personal project today by calling getLessons() from the view, which calls the getLessons() from the service. I'll answer my question for reference on Monday when I get back to work. It works, but feels wrong somehow, but I kinda like how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I posted the wrong ts and html files, but still had the issue with the files I posted. You can see the issue more with these files, and this is what I did to fix it. I call a function from the view that goes all the way to the service. I'm guessing this is a bad practice, but it's the only thing I found to work.

**lesson.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class Lesson {
  constructor(public id: number, public buttons: Object[]) {  }
}

@Injectable()
export class LessonService implements OnInit {

  private lessons: Lesson[] = [];
  public buttons: object[];
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.db.object('/lessons', { preserveSnapshot: true }).subscribe(lessons => {
      this.lessons = [];
      lessons.forEach(lesson => {
        this.lessons.push(new Lesson(
          lesson.key,
          lesson.val()['buttons']
        ));
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getLessons() { return this.lessons; }

  getLesson(id: number): Lesson {
    return this.lessons.filter(lesson => {
      return lesson.id === id;
    })[0];
  }

}
```

**lesson.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Lesson, LessonService } from './lesson.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private lessons: Lesson[];
  private lesson: Lesson = new Lesson(0, []);
  private errorMessage: string;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: LessonService
  ) {}

  getLessons() { return this.service.getLessons(); }

  gotoLesson(id) { this.router.navigate(['/lesson', id]); }

  getButtons() { return this.service.buttons; }

  doCLick(btnID) {
    console.log('clicked', btnID);
  }
}
```

**lesson.html**

```
<md-toolbar>
  <button md-button routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active">Home</button>
  <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="lessonsMenu">Lessons </button>
  <md-menu #lessonsMenu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <button md-menu-item *ngFor="let lesson of getLessons()" (click)="gotoLesson(lesson.id)">Lesson {{lesson.id}}</button>
  </md-menu>
  <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
  <button md-mini-fab color="primary" *ngFor="let button of getButtons()" (click)="doClick(button.id)" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <md-icon>{{button.icon}}</md-icon>
  </button>
  <button md-mini-fab style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <md-icon>search</md-icon>
  </button>
</md-toolbar>
```