# How MVC pattern can be explained in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Found a helpful blog for **[Angular: MVC Implementation](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/tutorial-angularjs-mvc-implementation)** but still looking for good explanation for **Angular 2**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### General

I think that the pattern is really quite language agnostic. That is to say, the design/architecture patterns are rather abstract, and implementing them in different languages follows this more abstract presentation. That is not to say we can not make it more concrete given an example language, such as C# or Java, or an example framework such as Angular2.

Given that you already read some source on the MVC pattern, I am assuming that you have an understanding of how the pattern looks like in it's abstract form. It's a separation of Model, View and Controller. I will not dive further into the abstract presentation of this. Let's just take a look at Angular2.

### Angular2-specific

Assuming that you are using **angular2-cli**. When you create a new component, a bunch of files are generated for you. The important ones are the ones ending on `component.html` and `component.ts` for understanding MVC. These are the view and controller respectively. The HTML, is what is presented to the user (along with some CSS for layout). It is easy to see how this represents the view. Next to it, we have the accompanying `component.ts` file. This is the controller. Essentially, it can choose which data to push to our view (.html) with the various forms of binding.

*If you do not use angular2-cli, you could have them combined in one file. The HTML section is our view, Typescript our controller.*

Lastly, we have the model. In angular2, the model will mostly be our `services`, which we can access through our controller. (sidenote: the services can be seen as another pattern, [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Sidenote to the sidenote: this is true in most cases but look on SO for some workaround))

Though our model can extend beyond that. Our 'backend' can have more classes, that our services use to process or store information for example. This can belong to our model as well. We can have a class file for `Person`. A `PersonService` can then manage an array of `Person`. We could say that `Person` is still a model class.

Answer (score 13):

Angular2 follows an MVC pattern.  The Model is represented by the factories and services which can be injected into the component class constructor via Dependency Injection. The Controller is the Component Class; factories and services are DI injected into the Component Class usually in the class constructor, and then used to set class member variables.  The View is the Component template which binds to the component class member variables.

[image]