# Angular 2 is MVVM or MVC

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, mvvm

I feel lost when I  read the previous questions about the architecture of angular 2,  whether it is MVC or MVVM. Some said that it is MVC and other MVVM. Can any one clear for me the architecture of Angular 2?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762515/is-angular2-mvc. But really: Does it matter? :)

Comment: Also: [Angular2: MVC, MVVM or MV*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950582/angular2-mvc-mvvm-or-mv?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 is based on component architecture, each component will have sub/chiild components, where as each component will follow MVC Architecture. Each Component will have its Class(assume as Controller), View, Attributes of Class(assume as Model) are binded to view, thus it will follow MVC internally.